# Show me flags even when they're supposed to be hidden

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, moderator-tools, flags

If I understand correctly, some flags on Stack Overflow are hidden from moderators for whatever reason. This behavior needs to be tweaked. This is what is happening now (tested with latest versions of Chrome and Firefox on Windows):

[image]

The banner on the bottom tells me there's a flag on the question, but I can't see it without opening its flag history. I don't know what purpose this serves.

The ones above are also absent from our moderator flag queue. But the worst ones close question flags that *do* show up on the mod queue. When I navigate away from the dashboard, I see **nothing** at all (no banner). I have to either go back to the dashboard or open the flag history:

[image]

This makes no sense. We should be able to see these flags like we see all other flags, on that little banner.

**Examples** (for mod eyes only): [Banner with no info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182114/oracle-numbering-update), [Nothing at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799909/pub-sub-using-httpport-80-no-wcf-client)

Comment: Aren't those flags that have already been resolved? Or are you saying that you want to see resolved flags too?

Comment: You get an empty banner when you visit the page? I don't think that's ever supposed to happen

Comment: @jmort253 They are active flags.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I believe this is SO-specific behavior.

Comment: Right, the banner being blank sounds more like a bug.

Comment: This has been ongoing for the past year. It's nothing new, really. It may even already have been reported a few times, and the last time I ever heard from Marc was when he thought he had this nipped in the bud only for it to escape his clutches and soil his triumph prematurely.

Comment: tl;dr: old caching ailment

Comment: That banner overlay is always wonky, I just keep it closed.

Comment: The overlay certainly isn't SO-specific; maybe the weirdness where a blank one comes up is, but I don't know why

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I meant the blank one. It's probably a side-effect of having some flags hidden from mods on SO.